# Video Streming server outbound bandwidth and providers

Tags: bandwidth, connection, video, streaming, video-streaming

Imagine the case of Twitter Periscope or Meerkat.The paradigm of their servers is that they recieve video from users and then stream it to a large amount of users (say > 100K for the sake of this argument).

Now, here is my confusion. Let's assume a video has a bit rate of 2Mb/s (Cause we're fancy and stream 1080p@30). Also assume there is only 1 guy broadcasting.

So:
this guy needs outbound bandwidth of 2Mbps (Which is OK)
the server inbound bandwidth needed is also ~2Mbps (Which is awesome)
however, the outbound bandwidth of the server should be 2Mbps*100K = 200 Gbps (holy cow)

The question which might be stupid to some, yet I still wonder, The connections I have seen for companies like comcast,ATT,Level3 are max 10Gbps

How do they manage such bandwidth in terms of outbound connection providers?

A 10Gbps connection per server machine?
A plan which I am not aware of?
Or they don't need more than 10Gbps at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

THe connect with multiple 10g connections. OBVIOUS, is it not?

> A plan which I am not aware of?

I am quite sure you are totally unaware of what is there outside what is offered to smaller customers ;)

Comment: But why would a company, say ATT allow multiple 10G connections but not one connection to suit all needs?

Comment: @Solo: Because networking equipment gets (kind of) exponentially  more expensive with higher bandwith beyond 10Gb/s...

Comment: @Sven - Thanks! so to sum it up... You go to ATT and say you want say 50Gbps outbound and they set 5 totally independent ports of 10Gbps in your data center to their backbone, right?

Comment: @Solo: To sum it up: You get someone who knows what he is talking about and they come up with a plan that makes sense for your specific scenario that also factors in things like future growth etc

Comment: @Sven - Not helpful... this community is all about learning not about learning that anything can be bought as a service of someone who knows...

Comment: @Solo Ignorant (as in: Ignoring - the site rules). This community (serverfault) is NOT about learning but about advice between professionals. If you want to learn, head over to superuser or any other site that is not explicitly for people with the basic knowledge.

Comment: @Solo: This community is for professional system administrators *exclusively*, deals only with practical technical problems you actually face and not with  theoretical "I always wanted to know" questions.